# Setting Global Variables in Java

Tags: java, variables, static

Here's my problem: I have a number of classes that need access to a specific value (such as an email address) and instead of declaring it again and again in each class I'd like to declare it once and access it using some sort of global variable.

Now before you naysayers start screaming (or down-voting this post) I am aware you could declare a class like this:

```
public class GlobalVar{

        public GlobalVar() throws Exception
    {

    }
    public static String email = "myemail@gmail.com";

 }
```

And access `email` anywhere by using `GlobalVar.email`

My problem is the value of email cannot be set as static because it comes from a text file (from key/property using Java `properties class`) and I don't see anyway to load the value from txt file if I set the variable to static.

I am basically storing a dynamically generated email in a file and retrieving it the next time I start the application. Of course I can attempt to retrieve it each time I need to use the variable but this is not elegant.

**Update:**

A potential solution has been proposed as follows:

```
public static String email = null;
static {
    email = "awesome@email.com"; // change to your initialization process
}
```

I thought this solution would work however the problem is that the value is generated dynamically at startup if a previous value does not already exist in the txt file. Basically, if it is the 1st time you are running the application a new value is generated. Otherwise the value is retrieved from a txt file (which was generated at a previous run of the program).

If I implement this solution the value of email will be equal to null (across the entire program) if this is the first time you run the program.

I basically need a way to initialize a static variable using a conditional statement but I don't know if this is possible.

Thanks

Comment: You could use a `static` initialize to load it.  Have a look at [Initializing Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) for more details.

Comment: Of course you can "set it as static"; why couldn't you? (Whether this is the best solution is, of course, another matter.)

Comment: @chrylis If I try I get `Unhandled exception type IOException` (unless I initialize variable using `static  { }` as some suggested.

Comment: in your load, can't you just `GlobalVar.setEmail` or something? so you can change the email whenever you want

Comment: there's nothing inelegant about retrieving the value from a `Properties` object whenver you need it. the properties API is designed for this sort of thing

Comment: It is tedious and elaborate. This: `public static String email = null;
static {
    email = "awesome@email.com"; // change to your initialization process
}` is 10X more elegant , faster and cleaner.

Comment: Read a book on encapsulation and other OO concepts.

Answer (score 1):

To initialize a static variable you can use `static` (see [static initialization blocks](http://Static%20Initialization%20Blocks)):

```
public static String email = null;
static {
    email = "awesome@email.com"; // change to your initialization process
}
```

An alternative would be to use a static function:

```
class Mail {
    public static String email = initializeMailVariable();

    private static String initializeMailVariable() {
        // initialization code goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: @JohnDoe, no. And actually it's better to use the `final` keyword

Answer (score 0):

Just set up your GlobalVar class to have getters and setters, when you read the file from whatever load method you're doing, call `GlobalVar.setEmail("whatever")` and then you can access it from anywhere with `GlobalVar.getEmail()`.

```
public class GlobalVar{

    private static String email = "";

    public static void setEmail(String email){
        this.email = email;
    }

    public static String getEmail(){
        return this.email;
    }
}
```